# SQL Server 2012 - Queries working executed one on one, but not in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to execute these two queries together:

```
ALTER TABLE afm.owned_properties_rpt_table 
ALTER COLUMN bl_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE afm.owned_properties_rpt_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT owned_properties_rpt_table_PK PRIMARY KEY (bl_id);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Mens. 8111, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 3
>   Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table
>   'owned_properties_rpt_table'.
>
> Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 3
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

It seems that somehow, the second line is being executed before the first one finishes.

I have tried changing semicolons by goes, using a begin transaction/commit transaction structure, and creating an auxiliary column where I copied the data in bl_id and then dropped the old column, all of them without success.

The SQL script needs to be executed on a client's server (where I can not intervene), so dividing the code is not an alternative.

I am sorry if I am missing something elementary, I have also searched for the same problem during several hours without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PK can not be null,, add default to the bl_id column. `ALTER TABLE afm.owned_properties_rpt_table ALTER COLUMN bl_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ABC';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE afm.owned_properties_rpt_table ALTER COLUMN bl_id CHAR(8) NOT NULL default 'sometest';
GO
ALTER TABLE afm.owned_properties_rpt_table ADD CONSTRAINT owned_properties_rpt_table_PK PRIMARY KEY (bl_id);
```

Comment: Above code is tested? need default value for the `bl_id`!

Comment: It was not necessary to add a default (all values in the table for bl_id where not null already). Using that go between the queries totally worked, thank you!